# Safari Export as PDF - crop / tile / posterize long PDF to multi pages

Tags: safari, pdf, crop

When I save a webpage with Safari's *> File > Export as PDF...*
Safari renders a long PDF in several (long) pages.

Here a screenshot of Preview's Crop Inspector, [200 inch](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/When-200-inch-page-limit-broken-q36927.aspx) seems to be the height values for each page.
Sometimes have over 10 pages because the webpages get pretty long with +100 comments.
[image]
[image]

So now I want to crop, tile or posterize these long pages into normal height.
I want to read them in portrait orientation on on old iPad 2 which has a screen resolution of 768px x 1024px.
The PDF I saved with Safari has already the 768px width because I used the *Responsive Design Mode*

I tried following tools to crop / tile / posterize the long pages:

- **ADOBE ACROBRAT PRO DC**
  *Print > Page Sizing & Handling > Poster > Print*
  ! The app crashes
- [**BRISS**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/)
  Never been able to get the crop arguments to work from the command line
  Auto cropping to a certain height does not work, even not in GUI mode
- [**PDFTILECUT**](https://github.com/oxplot/pdftilecut)
  Seems to work but can't set the margins to zero, get rid of the trim marks and set the `-tile-size` value correctly
- [**PDFPOSTER**](https://pdfposter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)
  Error in the Terminal
  `pdfposter: error: The input-file is either currupt or no PDF at all: Invalid Elementary Object starting with b'b' @7: b'3\n%\xc4\xe5\xf2\xe5\xeb\xa7\xf3\xa0\xd0\xc4\xc6\n3 0 obj\n<< /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 19229 >>\nstream\nx\x01\xd5\xbdi\x97\x1c\xc7\x95'`

I don't get it, the webpage is saved to PDF by Safari and corrupt?

- **UPDATE 1**: I managed something in PDFPOSTER, after "repairing" the PDF
  I have set the height of the `--poster-size` BOX to something really long: 100000pt
  `pdfposter -v -m 768x1024pt -p 768x100000pt in.pdf out.pdf`

That works for both pages, one after the other, but I can’t find a solution to set the Y coordinates of each page to 0
The pages always seem to start from the bottom of the poster size, leaving space at the top..

- **UPDATE 2**: attached a few pictures as why *Safari > File > Print* is NOT an option for me.

1. It leaves me with borders unable to remove
2. Dark Mode is not applied
3. Responsive layouts are not applied

[image]
[image]
[image]

- **UPDATE 3**:
  The last days I tried out libraries, toolkits, bindings, command line tools, modules, recipes ecc. like a mad man, but today I finally found my peace with [PYPDF](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)
  Now that I played around long enough with this [Cropping and Transforming example](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/cropping-and-transforming.html#cropping-and-transforming-pdfs) I am confident I can do what I want.

Basically with PYPDF you define:
`reader = PdfReader('mypdf.pdf')`
`writer = PdfWriter()`
I than loop over the pages `page_x = reader.pages[i]` from the input file, set mediaboxes for each "new" page and add it to the writer `writer.add_page(page_x)`
Finally write out with `writer.write()`

Hyperlinks remain intact!

Comment: Save the PDF from the print menu instead. That will place it on pages.

Answer (score 2):

> When I save a webpage with Safari's → File → Export as PDF...
> Safari renders a long PDF in several (long) pages.

This is expected behavior.  A webpage is not a printed page.  As you've found, it can be 200 inches or more.  As stated in the comments, the correct action here would have been to utilize *Print to PDF* so the pagination would be the standard US Letter size (8.5"x11").  The print engine would have automatically handled page margins, header, footer, gutter, etc. without you having to manually do it.

### So, how do we fix this?

> So now I want to crop, tile or posterize these long pages into normal height.

#### Option 1:  Print to PDF (again)

Using Adobe Acrobat or Preview, print the image to PDF using the standard settings.  This should paginate it correctly though it's impossible to guess where the page breaks would end up now.

#### Option 2, Part I:  Split the image into multiple files

> I want to read them in portrait orientation on on old iPad 2 which has a screen resolution of 768px x 1024px...The PDF I saved with Safari has already the 768px width because I used the Responsive Design Mode

For this task, we're going to use a (free) tool called [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/).  It's available via [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/GraphicsMagick/), [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/graphicsmagick), and [direct download](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/download.html).

We are going to "split" the image using the `convert` command with the `crop` and `adjoin` operators:

First, convert the PDF to an image. This is necessary because PDFs do not "break" easily.   For this I selected a PNG:

```
% gm convert input.pdf output.png
```

Next, crop the image by the desired (calculated) size:

```
gm convert -crop 768x990 input.pdf +adjoin output%04d.pdf
```

The output file `output%04d.pdf` uses a C++ [`printf`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) style `%d` output format. Simply put, it uses a signed four digit integer with leading zeros in the filename.  Example `output0001.pdf`.  This will create as many individual pages as necessary.

Please note:  Since it's not clear what the page margins were, I am using the raw values of US Letter or 8.5 inches wide and 11 inches long.  With the resolutions you used of 768px wide, this calculates to about 90-ish DPI; 72 DPI is the norm for a printed page whether on paper or viewing on an iPad.  The length value of 990px is calculated by multiplying 90DPI by 11 inches.

You might have to adjust to fit your margins.  If you do, remember to subtract the left and right margins from 8.5 then multiply by the DPI.  So, if your page has ½ inch margins all around, the formula to calculate crop size will be:  `8.5 - (2*0.5) * 72`.  It will be the same for the length except you'll substitute 11 for the 8.5.

#### Part II:  Recombine the pages into a single PDF

Now that we have all the individual pages created, we can recombine them into a single PDF file.  You can use either of two tools that you can use to accomplish this:  [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/) or [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/).  Both are available on MacPorts, but Homebrew doesn't have PDFBox.  You'll need to download it directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox)

- **PDFtk:**

  ```
  % pdftk *.pdf newDocument.pdf
  ```
- **PDFBox:**

  ```
  % java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.21.jar PDFMerger (output0001.pdf output0002.pdf...output000N.pdf) newDocument.pdf
  ```

(PDFTk seems easier to use, but I've found the output "better" with PDFBox.  YMMV)

Comment: US Letter size or A4 depending on print settings

Comment: Option 1 with Preview doesn't split it. Is that because it was a pdf containing an image?

Comment: It’s possible it won’t print.  I”ve never tried printing something that large.  That said, I’ve printed large images where it automatically split the image so I’m not sure what’s going on there.

Comment: Did you attempt option 2?

Comment: I tested this on my Mac and found that you must convert the PDF to an image first to make this work.  Once you have the image "split" to your specifications, you can convert it back to a PDF using the reverse of the command `gm convert input.png output.pdf`

Comment: Option2: It works with `gm convert input.pdf input.png` and `gm convert -crop 1676x2000 input.png +adjoin output%04d.png` Crop width same as width of output.png; need to fiddle more with height. I didn't have my input.pdf width 768. I didn't get the convert to work with input.pdf

Comment: Those crop dimensions ate huge!  It might help getting the dimensions of the original PDF. Use `gm identify input.pdf` and it will give you the dimensions of the document.  If the width is good, you might want to stay with that dimension.

Comment: Option 1: I updated the post as to why > Print is not an option for me. Option 2: before and go try out these tools... does it preserve HREF links? I imagine when you convert to image and than back to PDF all links will be lost?

Comment: Yes, links will be lost because it’s now an image. Remember a PDF isn’t meant to be modified (minor edits, yes but major changes, no). The only way around this would be to pass it through an OCR engine and save it as a PDF-A.  Your other option is to open the huge PDF in LibreOffice as that will allow you to “edit” it.  But you’ll have to manually paginate.

Comment: I am almost there with coherentpdf whilst keeping links intact, will post when I found my way out.

Comment: I contacted the developer of coherentpdf, unfortunately cutting (or de-imposing) is not supported (yet).

Comment: Of course, converting to an bitmap image may be a problem, as the text won't be searchable.

Comment: @FFish, i’m testing some OCR to maje the image a searchable PDF.  Stay tuned!

Comment: @benwiggy Many bitmaps are searchable because Ventura's spotlight indexer does read text in images.

Comment: @FFish I use OwlOCR as free or low cost image to pdf OCR. Like many tools it uses the OCR built into recent macOS.

Comment: @Gilby Conversion to bitmap is still lossy. It may be an unacceptable price for some.

Comment: Found my way out, for sure this time with pypdf, see update 3

Comment: You’ve found a ton of PDF tools.  I’ve been trying to get GhostScript to convert the image to a PDF-A (text searchable PDF)

Answer (score 0):

On iPad you can create a screenshot with `CMD`-`Shift`-`3`. What many people do not know is that you can actually create a screenshot not only of the visible screen but of the whole webpage. For this, use the same keyboard combination and then tap on the little preview window that appears at the bottom left. Then, at the top, select „Full Page“.

[image]

Comment: Cool, it does not work for me though... when I click on the thumbnail in the bottom left I just get a Finder Preview, without these options.

Comment: @FFish On occasion, it also did not work for me. I have no idea why. Recently it always worked. You can try to create a screenshot be pressing the power button and the volume up button at the same time when you look at a webpage in Safari.

Comment: Ah but you are saying on iOS? OK I see now "On iPad". My iPad is 15 years old LOL